# MS-Excel copy specific cells if cell.Value= "Yes"

Tags: excel, copy-paste, worksheet, vba

I would like to copy the cells from columns A, W and G from a worksheet "Recalculated FS" to another worksheet called "Tempo" if the cell value in the AI column of the same row = "YES".

This is the code I am using now,

```
Sub dural()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    ws.Name = "Tempo"
     For Each Cell In Sheets("Recalculated FS").Range("AI:AI")
        If Cell.Value = "YES" Then
            Sheets("Recalculated FS").Range("A:A").Copy Sheets("Tempo").Range("B:B")
            Sheets("Recalculated FS").Range("W:W").Copy Sheets("Tempo").Range("A:A")
            Sheets("Recalculated FS").Range("G:G").Copy Sheets("Tempo").Range("C:C")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

It doesn't work.
this picture illustate my need, each time AI = yes -- > we copy the value of A, G and W column
[image]
Help please.

Comment: Where on sheet "Tempo" do you need the cells copied?  E.g. if cell AI15 of "Recalculated FS" is the third row to have a "YES" in column AI, do you want `Sheets("Recalculated FS").Range("A15:A15")` copied to `Sheets("Tempo").Range("B3:B3")`, or do you want it copied to `Sheets("Tempo").Range("B15:B15")`, or do you want it copied some other place entirely?

Comment: Note:  I think a lot of the confusion about answering this question is due to an edit (by someone other than the OP) to the question which changed the first statement from `I would like to copy cell A,W,G from a worksheet "Recalculated FS" to another "Tempo" if "AI" cell value = "YES"` to be `I would like to copy **Columns A,W,G** from a worksheet "Recalculated FS" to worksheet "Tempo" if a cell in **Column AI** value = "YES".`  There is a major difference between copying a cell and copying a column.  I will edit it back to how it was.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use the following to copy the columns:

```
Sheets("Recalculated FS").Range("A:A").Copy Sheets("Tempo").Range("B:B")
Sheets("Recalculated FS").Range("W:W").Copy Sheets("Tempo").Range("A:A")
Sheets("Recalculated FS").Range("G:G").Copy Sheets("Tempo").Range("C:C")
```

*Note: The above point is now irrelevant as the OP has changed his code.*

2) To change the headings in the "Tempo" sheet, you could just say:

```
Sheets("Tempo").Range("A1").Value = "Heading for column A"
```

etc.

*Note: The above point is now irrelevant as the OP has removed this question from his post.*

3) Your `For Each Cell In Sheets("Recalculated FS").Range("AI:AI")` loop will perform the contents of the loop for **every** cell in column AI which means that, if column AI contains 10 cells with a value of "Yes", the three columns will be copied 10 times (each time copying exactly the same thing to exactly the same place).  (And it will go through the loop many, many, thousands of times looking at empty cells and deciding that it doesn't need to do anything - but still taking time to decide that.)

*Note: The above point is still relevant.*

Comment: thanks for your help, I need to add this 3 lines in the If clause , when I do it it never stop running? your 3rd point is not fair enough for me (Foreach), AI it's a single column with 120000 rows

Comment: Each of the three range.copy lines will copy one column from the Recalculate FS sheet to the Tempo sheet, so they can be placed inside your IF statement inside the loop, but it may not be a good idea to do so.  If AI contains 120000 rows, your loop will look at each of those 120000 cells in turn and decide whether or not the cell contains a value "YES".  If 2000 of them contain "YES", the three columns will be copied 2000 times, and for the other 118000 times through the loop nothing will be copied.  Are you wanting the columns copied 2000 times?  Or just once?

Comment: I changed my code and add a picture to illustrate my need , the code load and never stop..

Comment: and it copy all lines (cell.value="YES" not working)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to search for a YES value.

You can then copy the columns if a single YES is found.

```
Sub dural()

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Recalculated FS").Select
Columns("AI:AI").Select

Set cell = Selection.Find(What:="YES", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
'Search the column for a YES value

If cell Is Nothing Then
    'Do nothing if YES isn't found
Else
    'Copy columns if YES is found
End If

        If Len(ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value) <> 0 Then
            Sheets("Tempo").Name = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value
        Else
            'Don't change the name
        End If
'Rename the Tempo worksheet based on a cell value

End Sub
```

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Recalculated FS").Select
Columns("AI:AI").Select
Set cell = Selection.Find(What:="YES", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
'Search the column for a YES value
If cell Is Nothing Then
    'Do nothing if YES isn't found
Else
Sheets("Recalculated FS").Range("A:A").Copy Sheets("Tempo").Range("B:B")
Sheets("Recalculated FS").Range("W:W").Copy Sheets("Tempo").Range("A:A")
End If` not working too